# is there any bash symbol to represent redirection operand in Linux interactive use?

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for a shell parameter to represent the redirection operand.

e.g: `data/temp.txt` in this command:

```
cat file.txt > data/temp.txt
```

Is there any such bash special Parameters which will allow me to open the file that I am redirecting to in interactive use, after the command will exit ?

```
$ cat file.txt > data/temp.txt
$ vim data/temp.txt
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by the question. What is a "special parameter" to you, here? What is it you actually intend to accomplish?

Comment: `>` is of course a "symbol" in the lexer sense of the word, but I doubt that's what you actually mean.

Comment: ...in both shells, when `cat` is run, FD 1 will be opened to a file descriptor pointing to `data/temp.txt`

Comment: ...however, whether `cat` can *tell* that the name of the file it's writing to is `temp.txt`, or where that file is located, depends on operating-system extensions such as procfs, not shell functionality at all.

Comment: ...as such, for a shell to include such functionality, it would need to limit its operating system scope and portability -- not, generally, a well-advised choice.

Comment: ...anyhow, what's your real goal? To figure out where a redirection your script was started with is pointing to? If you specify your operating system, then that could well be possible (and, indeed, we almost certainly have a question already in the knowledge base on the topic for Linux).

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. OP, take a look at this: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Forgive me If my question was unclear. I just want to open the file that I previously edited. e.g: `cat file.txt > data/temp.txt && vim data/temp.txt `

Comment: If you're doing this interactively, `Alt-.` (alt period) will insert the last word of the previous command in the edit buffer (i.e. you'd type `vim ` and hit `Alt-.` to get `vim data/tmp.txt`). If you're doing this in a script (or interactively, too), you can just create a variable yourself: `file=data/tmp.txt; cat file.txt > "$file" && vim "$file"`

Comment: Ahh! If this is for interactive use, could you specify whether you have history expansion turned on? (BTW, as history expansions aren't generally available in scripts, this would make this a question more about interactive use than programming, and perhaps a better use for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) if that's what you want).

Comment: Thanks @melpomene `Alt-.` did the trick ! @charles-duffy: history-expansion is what I was looking for. I update my question to more reflect the scope of my question. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. But since the redirection operand usually is the last, you can use Bash's history expansion:

```
echo hello > testfile
cat !$      # cat testfile
```

Or for interactive session, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>esc</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> can be used to insert the last word of the previous line, as a comment pointed out.

[Bash documentation for history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators).

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility here is bash's process substitution -- if you're most interested in opening an editor on the output of `cat`, but you're not as interested in writing the output to a file, you can use

```
vim <(cat file.txt)
```

This writes stdout to a named pipe and opens the named pipe (probably named something like `/dev/fd/NN`) in a text editor. You make your edits, and you can then save your edits using `<esc>:w data/temp.txt` if you wish.